# FXML read text from pojo property

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml

I am totally new to `JavaFX` and I'm trying to show a text from a `pojo` property, like this:

```
public class Person {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class PersonPresenter {

    @FXML
    private Person person;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println("initialize");
        ReganteDTO regante = dao.getRegante(3);
        this.regante = new ReganteProperty(regante);
    }
}
```

I was hoping to be able to read the person's name from the `fxml` with something like:

```
<GridPane [...] fx:controller="mypackage.PersonPresenter">
    <Text id="my-text" text="${person.name}"/>
</GridPane>
```

All I have been able to find `google` around is declaring properties for each field. Is there no simpler way to read (I don't want to modify) a property from a `pojo`?

I'm using afterburner, but I don't think that has much to do with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why do you want to bind the Person's name to the Text in the fxml instead of binding it in the controllers `initialize()` method?

Comment: To avoid having to change the controller and the fxml for each person property. I'm coming from Angular where if you make an object available to the view, the view can access its properties. Isn't there a simple mechanism in FX to read properties from a pojo?

Comment: @FedericoNafria It's really not clear (at least to me) what you mean here. JavaFX follows more of a MVP-style architecture, where the view is basically passive and is manipulated by the presenter ("controller"). What do you mean by "change the controller and the fxml for each person property"? Perhaps you could explain more clearly the actual problem you are trying to solve, rather than trying to ask about fixing your solution, which just appears to be coming from the wrong direction entirely.

Comment: I was probably expecting from fxml to be something more powerful like jsp or jsf. What I mean is that if I want to show a new person property like `address` I would have to make changes both in the fxml and in the controller.

Comment: No, you really wouldn't have to do that.

Comment: How would I bind the `address` without changing the controller?

Comment: Can you step back and explain the actual problem you are trying to solve? I.e. you have a `Person` class with a fixed set of properties: name, address, email, perhaps. What UI are you trying to create?

Comment: Check the answer from @ItachiUchiha. what I mean is if there is a way to avoid the binding in the controller and let the fxml read the object properties. From what he says, I understand that is not possible.

Comment: It is possible, as he shows, but it is convoluted because it breaks the standard UI architectures. You haven't explained why you would want to avoid binding in the controller. (And you *still* haven't really explained what you are trying to achieve.)

Comment: I still don't really know what you're looking for. Have a look at [this example](https://github.com/james-d/ReactFXAfterburnerExample), `editor.EditorPresenter` binds the text fields bidirectionally to some properties. It uses ReactFX to manage "properties of properties".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question, just to give you a background on when to use the special character `$` and how do we normally use JavaFX application when it has a FXML, here is a short description.

JavaFX follows a MVP approach, where the view is a passive interface and the presenter(supervising controller) is responsible for retrieving data and formatting it before displaying it on the view.

[image]

If you have a model, you would want to load the data in the controller and let the controller handle the view.

```
public class PersonPresenter implements Initializable {    

    @FXML
    private Text myText;

    //Some how get the Person object reference
    Person person = getPerson();

    private void initialize() {
        myText.setText(person.getName());
    }
    ...
}
```

Your Fxml :

```
<GridPane [...] fx:controller="mypackage.PersonPresenter">
    <Text id="myText"/>
</GridPane>
```

If you make the name attribute of the Person class as a `StringProperty`, you can bind its value to the Text controls `textProperty()`, which will make sure that any change in the value of the name will be reflected in the Text.

```
private void initialize() {
    myText.textProperty.bind(person.nameProperty);
}
```

**Additional Information on FXML**

There might be scenario's where you would want to load values using the `$` notation.

Here is a section from JavaFX Pro book :

```
<fx:define>
   <Date fx:id="capturedDate"/>
</fx:define>
<Label fx:id="currentDateLabel" text="$capturedDate"/>
```

The defined Date was given the `fx:id` of capturedDate and the label used the variable for its text. Finally, the expression binding happens between a TextField and a Label:

```
<TextField fx:id="textField"/>
<Label text="${textField.text}"/>
```

The TextField was given the `fx:id` of textField and the label binds to the expression `textField.text`, with a result of the label mimicking what is typed in the text field.

I hope you get the idea. You can import resources into the FXML by using the FXMLLoader's [`setResources()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setResources-java.util.ResourceBundle-) which is more helpful for loading key-value pairs for e.g. a properties file.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes! But that is what you would have done in the FXML as well. *Unrelated, you are using a text and not a TextField in your example.*

Comment: The big difference is that I would have a single point of change.

Comment: Yes, but this is how JavaFX is designed and I have never seen anyone injecting values in the FXML. All the controls are injected into the controller by the FXMLLoader and the values are populated int these controls via the controller.

Comment: I guess what I am not understanding in this whole discussion is: " I would have a single point of change". What is changing?

Comment: @James_D From what I understood, the OP wanted to push everything to the FXML, so that he doesn't have to deal with binding the model data to the view elements *in the controller*. This would result in making all the *data binding logic* reside in the View. But, again, reading through your discussion with him (*specifically the JSF part*) IMO the OP is kind of ignorant of how MVC/MVP pattern works. Again, that is my opinion, may be I am wrong and I have misunderstood his question.

Comment: Regardless of architecture, he is implying that if he managed the binding in FXML he would somehow have less to manage than if he managed it in the controller. I guess that's what I'm not seeing.

Comment: @FedericoNafria can you edit the question to include FXML code you would like to write that shows what you mean by it having a "single point of change", and compare it to the equivalent controller code, which presumably doesn't have a single point of change.

Comment: What I was looking for is some way to access objects properties, as I put in the question, something like `${person.name}` just like other MVC oriented frameworks allow to do (JSP, JSF, Angular). I know that in a MVC you are not supposed to manipulate data int the view and that the view only responsibility is showing it. 
What I mean by single point of change is that, when I want to show a new property that is already in `Person` I would only need to change the FXML, not also the controller.
Anyway from what I've understood this is not possible in FXML.

Comment: With the techniques you've been shown, though, if you want to change the property displayed by a text field (or anything else), you only have to change the controller, not the FXML. So you still have a "single point of change". And, as shown, you can always bind in the FXML using `text="${person.name}"`, although it's unusual and initially getting the `person` object into the FXML namespace might need some work. But honestly, I'm really not sure I (or @ItachiUchiha) understand what you're asking, and it would *really* help if you would create a specific example.

Comment: In short, I suspect that what you want *can* be done in JavaFX (after all, a static UI framework has the ability to do a lot more than a framework that is constrained to sit on top of the http request-response lifecycle), but we just don't understand what you are asking. (So stop repeating the same phrase; you need to ask it a different way.)

Comment: @FedericoNafria Lets say that in future the Person model changes and has an extra field. I think what you are trying to achieve here is when that happens you need to change the model and view i.e. add a new control ( may be a textfield ) for displaying the new value added in the model without having to do any stuff in the controller. In a normal scenario, you would have to change the model, change the view to add the control and change the controller for adding the control and bind the model with the control. Am I getting it right?